# How to get an array from JSON in the Azure Data Factory?

Tags: sql, json, rest, azure-data-factory

My actual (not properly working) setup has two pipelines:

1. Get API data to lake: for each row in metadata table in SQL calling the REST API and copy the reply (json-files) to the Blob datalake.
2. Copy data from the lake to SQL: For Each file auto create table in SQL.

The result is the correct number of tables in SQL. Only the content of the tables is not what I hoped for. They all contain 1 column named odata.metadata and 1 entry, the link to the metadata.
If I manually remove the metadata from the JSON in the datalake and then run the second pipeline, the SQL table is what I want to have.

Have:

```
{  "odata.metadata":"https://test.com", 
"value":[
{
  "Key":"12345",
"Title":"Name",
"Status":"Test"
}]}
```

Want:

```
[{
"Key":"12345",
"Title":"Name",
"Status":"Test"
}]
```

I tried to add $.['value'] in the API call. The result then was no odata.metadata line, but the array started with {value: which resulted in an error copying to SQL

I also tried to use mapping (in sink) to SQL. That gives the wanted result for the dataset I manually specified the mapping for, but only goes well for the dataset with the same number of column in the array. I don't want to manually do the mapping for 170 calls...

Does anyone know how handle this in ADF? For now I feel like the only solution is to add a Python step in the pipeline, but I hope for a somewhat standard ADF way to do this!

Comment: Can your problem be simplified to how to parse the result from API call and stored the parsed result to a SQL table?

Comment: Hi Ray, I think multiple solutions are possible at different places: change the API call in Step 1 or the sink options , change the upload to SQL in step 2, add an extra copy step in to extract the arrays and others. But the ADF is a given. The answer I look for has to work there. So I would say simplifying not necessarily speed things up, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can add another pipeline with dataflow to remove the content from JSON file before copying data to SQL, using flatten formatters.

**Before flattening the JSON file**:

This is what I see when JSON data copied to SQL database without flattening:
[image]

**After flattening the JSON file**:

Added a pipeline with dataflow to **`flatten`** the JSON file to remove 'odata.metadata' content from the array.

*Source preview*:
[image]

*Flatten formatter*:

Select the required object from the Input array
[image]

After selecting **value** object from input array, you can see only the values under **value** in Flatten formatter preview.

[image]

*Sink preview*:

[image]

File generated after flattening.
[image]

Copy the generated file as Input to SQL.

[image]

**Note**: If your Input file schema is not constant, you can enable `Allow schema drift` to allow schema changes

[image]

Reference: [Schema drift in mapping data flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-schema-drift)